# Elasticsearch aggregation query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nosql

I have a collection of documents stored in elasticsearch, they look like this:

```
{
  "id": "12312312",
  "timestamp": "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000",
  "unit": {
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "unit-4"
  },
  "samples": [
    {
      "value": 244.05435180062133,
      "aggregation": "M",
      "type": {
        "name": "SomeName1",
        "display": "Some name 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 251.19450064653438,
      "aggregation": "I",
      "type": {
        "name": "SomeName2",
        "display": "Some name 2"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I would like to run an aggregation query against it which would return counts of `unit.id` per buckets for property `samples.value`,
query should be based on `samples.type.name` and `samples.aggregation`. I've produced something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gte": "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000",
            "lte": "2015-11-30T23:59:59.999",
            "format": "date_hour_minute_second_fraction"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "nested": {
          "path": "samples",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                "match": {
                  "samples.type.name": "SomeName1"
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "0": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "samples"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "samples.value",
            "interval": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm querying `http://localhost:9200/dc/sample/_search?search_type=count&pretty` . But this returns counts of nested documents in samples array.
But I need to count distinct `unit.id` per bucket...

Can you guys help me please?

**Edit:** added mapping

```
{
  "dc" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "sample" : {
        "unit" : {
          "properties" : {
            "name" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }}},
        "samples" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "aggregation" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "type" : {
              "properties" : {
                "display" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                },
                "name" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "value" : {
              "type" : "double"
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        }}}}}
}
```

**Edit**
I'll try to rephrase it...I want to get count of units per bucket defined by "histogram_samples_value". That means sum of this counts should be total number of units. And to test it I wrote a query which filters only one unit (many documents with different sample values) - all but one "histogram_samples_value" buckets should contain count=0 and one bucket should contain count = 1 .

Comment: Could you add your mappings? That'd make things easier.

Comment: Mapping added, if necessary I can probably even change document structure - I'm expecting to have up to 100 mil. documents in that index.

Comment: This seems better. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but why do you use `histogram` aggregation? Your requirements do not seem to need it at all. Also, could you add minimum expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want with the [reverse nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html), like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "nested_samples": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "samples"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "histogram_samples_value": {
               "histogram": {
                  "field": "samples.value",
                  "interval": 10
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "reverse_nested_doc": {
                     "reverse_nested": {},
                     "aggs": {
                        "terms_unit_id": {
                           "terms": {
                              "field": "unit.id"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e93dbddbbc4a841af5d9ce687a543a2914457d31

Comment: hey, thanks for sample, but this query returns histogram buckets filled with buckets based on "unit.id" term and they are the same for every "histogram" bucket. It's not precisely what I wanted.
I'll try to rephrase it...I want to get count of units per bucket defined by "histogram_samples_value". That means sum of this counts should be total number of units. And to test it I wrote a query which filters only one sample - all but one "histogram_samples_value" buckets should contain count=0 and one bucket should contain count = 1

Comment: I probably have to use filter aggregation with cardinality aggregation somehow.